# Перевод отрицательных чисел в двоичную систему счисления

Tags: c, системы-счисления, преобразование-типов

Почему после перевода в двоичную систему счисления вывод всё равно с минусом? Я ведь отдельно рассмотрел случай для отрицательных чисел. Для них тип данных меняется на unsigned, почему не работает то?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, base;
    base = 2;
    unsigned char minus = 0;
    unsigned int digits[640];
    int count;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    
    if (num < 0) {
        (unsigned int)num;
        for (count = 0; num != 0; count++) {
            digits[count] = num % base;
            num /= base;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (count = 0; num != 0; count++) {
            digits[count] = num % base;
            num /= base;
        }
    }
    
    int iter = count - 1;
    while (iter >= 0) {
        printf("%d ", digits[iter]);
        iter--;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строке

```
(unsigned int)num;
```

Эта строка не изменяет тип переменной `num`. Она создает новое значение, которое нужно куда-то сохранить, чтобы потом использовать в вычислениях. Вот эту часть кода

```
if (num < 0) {
    (unsigned int)num;
    for (count = 0; num != 0; count++) {
        digits[count] = num % base;
        num /= base;
    }
}
else {
    for (count = 0; num != 0; count++) {
        digits[count] = num % base;
        num /= base;
    }
}
```

можно заменить на это:

```
unsigned int tmp = (unsigned int)num;
for (count = 0; tmp != 0; count++) {
    digits[count] = tmp % base;
    tmp /= base;
}
```

Для `8` получим вывод:

```
1 0 0 0
```

Для `-8` получим вывод:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

что и есть `-8` в двоичном представлении.

Comment: а это не вывод в дополнительном коде случаем?я просто смотрю  8 и -8 по-разному представлены.

Comment: @7w1W1w7 не понимаю о чём Вы. Можно поконкретнее?

Comment: Дополнительный код  —  способ представления отрицательных целых чисел в компьютерах. Он позволяет заменить операцию вычитания на операцию сложения и сделать операции сложения и вычитания одинаковыми для знаковых и беззнаковых чисел, чем упрощает архитектуру ЭВМ. тобишь  получить положительное представление в бинарной системе счисления и для положительных, и для отрицательных чисел.